# Decode URL in bash

Tags: regex, bash, url, sed, cgi

I'm trying to decode GET arguments in pure bash.

I.e.: `hello+%26+world` should become `hello & world`

So far I've managed to get this:

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
echo "Content-type: text/plain"
echo ""

CMD=`echo "$QUERY_STRING" | grep -oE "(^|[?&])cmd=[^&]+" | sed "s/%20/ /g" | cut -f 2 -d "="`
CMD="${CMD//+/ }"

echo $CMD
```

which replaces all the `+` with a space.

Is there a better way to do this? Or do I just have to look for each possible encoded special character and replace it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use this function for URL decoding:

```
decodeURL() { printf "%b\n" "$(sed 's/+/ /g; s/%\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/\\x\1/g;')"; }
```

Then test it as:

```
decodeURL <<< 'hello+%26+world'
hello & world
```

**Explanation:**

- `printf %b` - expands backslash escape sequences in the corresponding argument
- `s/+/ /g` - Replace each `+` by a space
- `s/%\([0-9a-f][0-9a-f]\)/\\x\1/g` - Replace each `%` followed by 2 hex characters by literal `\x` and same hex characters so that `printf` can print equivalent ASCII character for it

Comment: Thanks, that seems to work, but how can I execute this? The string returned is a command like `ls -al` that I would like to execute and print the results

Comment: I had to match on the capital hex characters as well: `s/%\([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]\)/\\x\1/g`

Comment: Yes that's right @angerelle. gnu sed also supports `/i` mode for ignore case matching.

Comment: Here is an example in a script where I assign the result to a variable.  I had to add an extra \\ before the `x` .  The example is taking parameter 3 in a shell script file . 

`export DECODE_URL=\`printf "%b\n" "$(echo $3 | sed 's/+/ /g; s/%\([0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]\)/\\\\x\1/g;')"\``
`

Comment: I'd remove the `\n` if I were you. Don't alter the input, it is not your call to make. Also, the [...] stuff is unnecessary, since URL encoding requires % to be %%-encoded as well.